# assigning css into a class in a twig form

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, combobox

I am beginner dev. in symfony 2 and twig and I would like to add a bootstrap combobox https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/ that I have found on the net.
I want to add this combobox on my twig template. However as it is written here:

```
<select class="combobox">
  <option></option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
</select>
```

it is used basic values from css ...but what I want to do,listing:

```
 {{ form_row(form.city) }}
```

this in combobox...

as further example it is written:http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template

A clear help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ form_row(form.city, {'attr': {'class': 'class-name'}}) }}
```

or

```
{{ form_widget(form.city, {'attr': {'class': 'class-name'}}) }}
```